# Use the Service Layer in the ASP.Net Core 5 API in External Project

Tags: c#, api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net5

In my API I have two layer with the API Project (ServiceLayer and DataLayer)

I want to reuse the service layer as dll in an External ASP.Net framework 4.7 Project
I have a problem using the DLL because of the Dependency Injection of the dataLayer repository inside the serviceLayer classes.

[image]

This is the code for the serviceLayer Class

```
    public class EmployeeService: IEmployeeService
    {
        IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository;
        public EmployeeService(IEmployeeRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
            this.EmployeeRepository = repository;
        }  
        public Employees GetAllPersonsById(int id)
        {
         return EmployeeRepository.GetById(id);
        }
    }
    public interface IEmployeeService {
      public  Employees GetAllPersonsById(int id);
    }
```

I use the DLL in the Other projects as follow

```
using  ServiceLayer; //dll
public partial class AspFrameWorkProject: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // An error occurred since it need dependincy Injection
        EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
      }
}
```

Comment: After reading your question twice, it's unclear what the problem is you are trying to solve. The `EmployeeService` does not have a default constructor, meaning that the code inside your `Page_Load` method will not compile. But what do you want? Is your question about integration of DI in ASP.NET Web Forms? Or is your question about reuse of the service layer without hard dependency to the data layer? Or something else? Can you elaborate?